# How to get Cursor position in Ckeditor html format

Tags: ckeditor, position, cursor, ckeditor4.x, cursor-position

i am using ckeditor. i want to get last word when i press space and it will replace with a random word. i able able to get last word from the textarea and replace it with random word. but when i style a text (bold or italic) i am not able to get the exact cursor position. Because if my text is bold or italic and when i replace it with random word after replacement random word also bold or italic.
var r = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0];

```
    // var start = r.startOffset;
    // var end = r.endOffset;
    // r.collapse( 1 );
    // r.setStartAt( ( r.startPath().block || r.startPath().blockLimit ).getFirst(), CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_START );
    // var docFr = r.cloneContents();
    // var data = docFr.$.textContent
    // var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length);
    // var randomword = (name[random]);
    // var res  =data.split(" ")
    // var lastword = (res[res.length-1])
    // text1 = text.substring(0,datalen-1) + randomword +  text.substring(datalen+3, text.length);
```

The problem is in last line. I am not able to replace the word at exact position.
please help me out

Comment: var name = ["Usman","Hamza","Faisal","Wajahat","Yasir","Noman","Majid"];

Comment: var datalen = data.length
  var textlen = text.length